# Conflicting Android error messages: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

Originally I got this error:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first

at

```
customSection.addView(customLayout);
```

So I added

```
((LinearLayout)customLayout.getParent()).removeView(customLayout);
```

and now get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**So if the child has a parent, and I must first remove the child from the parent, why does getParent() return null?**

I have an abstract fragment that allows derived classes to supply a custom layout for the list adapter. Relevant code:

Binding:

```
public void bind(DataObject row) {
    View customLayout = getChildItemView(row);
    if (customLayout != null) {
        ((LinearLayout) customLayout.getParent()).removeView(customLayout);
        customSection.removeAllViews();
        customSection.addView(customLayout);
        customSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        customLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}

protected View getChildItemView(CommonRow row) {
    if (parentView == null) {
        parentView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_custom_section,
                        new LinearLayout(getActivity()), true);
        label = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.txtData1Label);
        value = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.txtData1Value);
    }
    label.setText("Minimum");
    value.setText(manager.formatMoney(((SpecificDataRow) row).minimum));
    return parentView;
}
```

I've also tried `inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_custom_section, null)` ... false, null / false, what gives?

EDIT:

@allprog, I knew some cleanup was needed. I wrote this at the end of the day somewhat in a hurry. I have since cleaned up the code, and separated out the binding and inflating of the view. Cleaned up code:

```
private class ViewHolder {
....

       public ViewHolder(View v) {
            Butterknife.inject(this, v);
            View custom = createCustomView(customSection);
            if (custom != null) {
                customSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                customSection.addView(custom);
            }
        }

        public void bind(CommonRow row) {
            ......

            bindCustomView(row, customSection);
        }

}
```

Child class:

```
    @Override
    protected View createCustomView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_custom_section, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    protected void bindCustomView(CommonRow row, ViewGroup section) {
        TextView label = Views.findById(section, R.id.txtData1Label);
        TextView value = Views.findById(section, R.id.txtData1Value);

        label.setText("Minimum");
        value.setText(manager.formatMoney(((SpecificRow) row).minimum));
    }
```

suitianshi got it first, with my original [unkempt] code that was the solution.

Comment: What is `customSection`? Can you show the code where it is first initialized?

Comment: It is in the getChildItemView(CommonRow row) method. parentView = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_custom_section, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), true);

Comment: Can you post the XML for list_item_custom_section? I suspect that you are trying to add the view to itself. Plus the variable `customSection` would still need to be declared (and set) somewhere. Can you post that code?

Comment: There's something missing - as @JStevenPerry asked, the `customSection` initialization is nowhere. What you've answered is the `customLayout` inflater. We'd need to see how's `customSection` defined and what it even is.

Comment: Try to cleanup your code. As @Dmide points it out, you use a field for parentView. This is a bad idea. Also, `getChildItemView` despite its name actually has side effects. I guess, if you clean up this chaos, everything will start working as it should. (PS: the debugger is your friend!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
public void bind(DataObject row) {
    View customLayout = getChildItemView(row);
    if (customLayout != null) {
         if(customLayout.getParent() != null) {
             ((LinearLayout)customLayout.getParent()).removeView(customLayout);
         }

         customSection.removeAllViews();
         customSection.addView(customLayout);
         customSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
         customLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

I have read related source code, `getParent` should return non-null value when `view` has a parent. You should **make sure it actually has a parent** before casting and calling `removeView`

Wish this helps.

source code :

in `View` :

```
public final ViewParent getParent() {
        return mParent;
    }
```

in `ViewGroup.addViewInner`

```
if (child.getParent() != null) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("The specified child already has a parent. " +
         "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.");
}
```

Comment: I understand that part, the problem is that customSection.addView(customLayout) fails with the error in OP title. So I can check for null all day but it still does not help me remove the customLayout from its original, [apparantly null] parent. Does not make sense to me.

Comment: added source code to my answer. You mean you get that exception but `getParent` reuturns null? that's really strange!

Comment: and did you try casting `ViewParent` to `ViewGroup` instead of `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: All of the addView methods in ViewGroup eventually go through `addViewInner()`. This is where the IllegalStateException comes from. If `getParent()` returns null, this never gets thrown in the first place. Are you absolutely sure you're not accidentally adding the same view to the same parent more than once? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java

Answer (score 2):

As I can see your `parentView` is a field variable, this is the key. So what I suspect is really going on:

First call of `bind()`: you creating `parentView` and it is not have a parent yet, `customSection.addView(customLayout);` works fine, but after you added a check for parent it fails here.

Second call of `bind()`: `parentView` is now have a parent and your added check should work now, but you failed at the previous step. Without a check you are failing here with exception in title.

Solution: check for the presence of parent and remove it only if necessery.

Answer (score 0):

First of all LayoutInflater inflate method always returns view without parent.

if `attachToRoot == true` the `parentView` will be that `new LinearLayout(getActivity())`

if `attachToRoot == false` the `parentView` will be inflated `R.layout.list_item_custom_section` whatever it is.

in **both** cases the `((LinearLayout) customLayout.getParent())` will be null. Thats why you are getting `NullPointerException`. You can see it in return statement in [LayoutInflater documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29).

As is written above declaring `parentView` as field is **bad aproach**, it should be method parameter that you will inflate if == null (approach from AdapterView).

BTW: line 9 in your code if would be called it would throw `NullPointerException` because it is called only in case that `customLayout == null`!!!