# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first”

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to add a marginTop of 20 using Java if the Android Version is Kitkat or above. I am getting an error The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
I have tried these but to no avail.

[The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil)

[Conflicting Android error messages: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642016/conflicting-android-error-messages-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-yo)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.appex.tryproject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple;
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.readystatesoftware.systembartint.SystemBarTintManager;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate p;
    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_r);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        LinearLayout Main_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 0);
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        linearLayout.addView(Main_layout, layoutParams);
        SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
        tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
        tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
    }
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    TextView orText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.optionView);
    orText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LayoutRipple RegisterButton=(LayoutRipple)findViewById(R.id.register);
    RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    com.rey.material.widget.Button LoginEmail=(com.rey.material.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    LoginEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EmailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    p = (ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate)findViewById(R.id.progressBarCircularIndeterminate);
    p.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EventActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName());
    intent.putExtra("mode","google");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);}
    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/container">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                />
            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
                android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
            <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
                android:text="@string/emailButton"
                style="@style/buttong"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:id="@+id/emailLogin"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="18.5sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="18.5sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/optionView" />
        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18.5sp"
                android:text="@string/reg"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark"
                 />
        </com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_r"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/primary" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appex.tryproject/com.appex.tryproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
            at com.appex.tryproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting an error The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first, at com.appex.tryproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
which is `linearLayout.addView(Main_layout, layoutParams);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change this:

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

to this:

```
((ViewGroup)Main_layout.getParent()).removeView(Main_Layout);
```

The linearLayout doesn't have any views yet (you just created it), so the linearLayout.removeAllViews() call is redundant. What you need isn't to remove all views from the Main_Layout's new parent, but to remove the Main_Layout from its previous parent.

What I would probably do instead to make the code a little more readable is to wrap Main_Layout in another layout so that then you could do something like this:

```
    LinearLayout Main_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    RelativeLayout wrapper = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    wrapper.removeView(Main_layout);
    LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 0);
    linearLayout.addView(Main_layout, layoutParams);
    wrapper.addView(linearLayout);
    //more code
```

Then for your toolbar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_r"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@color/primary" />
        <include layout="@layout/main"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```